Real-time collision avoidance using ROS2/moveit2
I am looking to implement real-time collision detection for a robotic arm based on incoming pointcloud data from a LiDAR sensor monitoring the scene. I do not need to check for self-collisions and don't need functionality for path planning. I simply want to know when the robot is getting near something to slow down and then stop if at a minimum distance.
I have been researching existing solutions and have seen Moveit recommended, but I have had a hard time picking up ROS(2) and Moveit(2). I think I am getting to a level where I could start working on a solution using Moveit(2), but I am looking for some advice before I start.

Does MoveIt(2) allow for real-time update and collision checking between robot and scene? (I have seen it mentioned that it only updates the scene when the robot is not moving)

Given that I don't need the path planning functionality, would it be simpler to manage this myself? I.e. Publish an OctoMap that is updated with incoming pointclouds, use fcl to create collision objects and update their positions to match the robot pose, calculate closest distance between OctoMap and robot collision objects.


